# python how to read a textfile and return a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

The question is to read a text file and return a dictionary like below.

this the text file

USER
fjeen

NAME
Filcon Jeen

EMAIL
filcon.jeen@clasic.edu.tr

PHONE
123-234-3333

This should be the return

```
 {'fjeen':['Filcon jeen', 'filcon.jeen@clasic.edu.tr','123-234-3333']
```

This is what I've tried but does not seem to work.

```
def read():
with open("profiles.txt","r") as text:
    return dict(line.strip().split() for line in text)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 1, in 
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 3, in read
    pass
builtins.ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: Is there `}` at the end of the line ??

Comment: Please define "*does not seem to work*". What output are you getting? If you are getting an error, please post the **full text** in your question.

Comment: it does not return anyting......

Comment: You're wrong, it can't not return anything. Unless you don't use it, of course. Better post a few lines of the input file as well as some code using your function.

Comment: I posted the whole question and errors i am getting now

Answer (score 0):

If your file is actual Python representation of object you should use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or
>   node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
>   structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and
>   None.

```
import ast
with open("profiles.txt") as f:
    loaded = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

If your file is JSON-encoded object you should use [json.load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a
>   JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

```
import json
with open("profiles.txt","r") as f:
    loaded = json.load(f)
```